# Using array sort to rearrange elements in vue not working on mobile?

Tags: arrays, vue.js, cross-browser, vuejs2, vuex

I'm having an issue where I'm outputting a list of components then reordering them. 
This works in my desktop chrome but not in mobile safari or chrome.
Anyone ever run into this?

For more info, I have a vuex module that manages the entity array and I commit this mutation to reorder them:

`state.entities.sort((a, b) => parseInt(a.initiative) < parseInt(b.initiative))`

Then in a component, I am outputting markup according to this array of entities:

`<entity v-if="showEntityList"
        v-for="entity in entities" 
        :key="entity.id"
        :entity="entity"/>`

Answer (score 5):

Figured it out!

I had to change this:

```
state.entities.sort((a, b) => parseInt(a.initiative) < parseInt(b.initiative))
```

to this:

```
state.entities.sort((a, b) => {
    if(parseInt(a.initiative) < parseInt(b.initiative)) {
        return 1
    }

    if(parseInt(a.initiative) > parseInt(b.initiative)) {
        return -1
    }

    return 0
})
```

The mobile browsers are just more strict with how you determine order it looks like.

Comment: Thanks, I had the same problem in Chrome (although it was working in Firefox).

Comment: Same problem, works fine in Firefox but Chrome. I wonder, what would be the reason? :/

Comment: The sort method is just slightly different between Chrome and Firefox. You have to be more specific in your implementation for it to work the same on both.

Comment: simplify to `state.entities.sort((a, b) => parseInt(a.initiative) - parseInt(b.initiative))`. (Notice the `minus` sign)